# Average ratio of upvotes and downvotes

Tags: discussion, voting

I am interested in some site statistics. There are no similar questions in the "May Already Be Answered" box.

What is the average ratio of up votes to down votes on open questions?

What is the average ratio of up votes to down votes for members with over 5000 points?

Does the site keep those types of statistics?

(Sorry about the discussion tag. It seemed closest to what I'm interested in).

Comment: What do you mean by average ration? it is not cleared.

Comment: Well, a question might show +3. That +3 could be +5/-2. I'm interested in knowing the ratio of those votes across all open questions. Similarly, members cast votes. Their history may include 16 up votes and 3 down votes. So I'm interested in the average ratio for all members with over 5000 points.

Comment: The site keeps the data, but you have to use [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com). Need to write some T-SQL query though. Edit: I'm too fast to comment, I'm not sure individual upvote/downvote is recorded per post.

Answer (score 10):

If we normalize the data on a per-user level (i.e. a user with 1 up / 10 down counts the same as a user with 100 up / 1000 down), we get a ratio of:

```
0.88433070404092 upvotes : 0.11566929595906 downvotes
```

(Ignoring the 27 users with >= 5000 reputation that's never voted)

[Data Explorer Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/185300).

---

On a post level, the only thing available is `Score`, not upvotes and downvotes, and the average score per open question is:

```
1.626721
```

[Data Explorer Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/185305).

And some similar stats:

Average score per closed question:

```
1.109299
```

Average score per answer:

```
2.146468
```

Average score per Community Wiki post:

```
Post           Question      Answer
12.723746      23.576204     10.054062
```

Answer (score 7):

This isn't an exact average, but there are two queries on the data explorer that show people that down vote the most and the people that upvote the most. Both of these assume at least one vote.

- [Upvote to Downvote ratio](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/184902/votes-upvote-to-downvote-ratio)
- [Downvote to Upvote ratio](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/185296/votes-downvote-to-upvote-ratio)

Interesting notes:

- The worst up to down ratio is 1:1337 from a 280K+ user. I'd love to know what that one upvote was.
- The worst down to up ratio is 1:11489 from a 37K+ user.

Another query I found while digging is the [Voting Ratio for the last 90 days](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/179710/voting-ratio-last-90-days). As of this week's data dump, it stands at 3,547,286 up to 421,125 down.

Comment: That 280k user is very part of a select group that is superior to the rest in terms of ability or qualities.

Comment: Hey @Andy, you should have just gotten an email from me inviting you to a pre-screening session hosted by Stack Exchange. We've got a date this upcoming Monday and Tuesday, so if you are interested, could you let me know what times might work best for you?