# #Upvotes/#Downvotes = 6; is that OK?

Tags: discussion, reputation, downvotes, statistics, site-analytics

I just reached 25k rep and gained access to the site's analytics, where with a quick glance I saw that the number of upvotes is six times greater than the number of downvotes.

Since the voting system is for the quality assurance of Stack Overflow, I was wondering if that ratio makes sense. And if it is not, does that mean that the users prefer to upvote, rather than downvote (which could be the result of the penalty a downvote takes on an answer-which might explain the ratio after all)?

---

Related: [Average ratio of upvotes and downvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251733/average-ratio-of-upvotes-and-downvotes?rq=1).

Comment: Part of it is the cost to down vote questions but there are users who flat out refuse to down vote anything. I don't know how common they are but every once in a blue moon someone will admit to as much. I recently ran into a user who insisted that down voting a question no one could understand was *irrational*.

Comment: The number, by itself, doesn't actually tell you much.  It doesn't tell you if people are inherently more inclined to upvote content than they are to downvote it, or if there is simply 6x more good content than bad content (In reality, it's undoubtedly some of both, but you don't know *how much* of each is at play).

Comment: Also, if the vote counts are ignoring deleted questions, that would skew the numbers too. A lot of content that gets down voted ends up deleted.

Comment: @BSMP that's bad. Hmm Servy you have a point here...

Comment: You would actually need #upvotes/questions/total votes on questions/questions, same for answer, #votes/#posts, etc. and compare that.

Comment: Also, downvote needs more rep than upvote (you can upvote in any sites just with association bonus rep), and casual users tend not to downvote because they aren't sure if it worths the downvote, compared to upvoting answers that are useful even slightly for them

Comment: For context, [the ratio of users who can only upvote to users who can downvote is about 2:1](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/675814/number-of-users-who-can-vote)

Comment: @ryanyuyu That's a somewhat misleading stat, as a much higher percentage of the users in the former group aren't active on the site.  If you look at users who have been active recently you'll get a very different number.

Comment: @Servy that's true.  To be fair, the 6:1 ratio proposed in this question is probably also misleading for the same reason.  It includes all of the historic, highly upvoted questions (like the branch prediction one).  I don't know enough stat/SQL to better represent either of these numbers.

Comment: @ryanyuyu [I agree that the question's stat isn't particularly meaningful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349720/upvotes-downvotes-6-is-that-ok?noredirect=1#comment476211_349720) (and your reason is also a reason why the stat isn't useful, among others).

Comment: @BSMP I... I will admit to it as well. I tend to save my downvotes for things that I feel very strongly about (usually answers) and poorly worded questions just make me scratch my head, comment asking for clarification, and occasionally vote to close. The 1-point cost isn't very heavy (particularly as I'm over 3k) but there's still that psychological barrier.

Comment: i mean... people upvote answers just because they tried, while saying it doesn't work in the same sentence.

Comment: I'm with other people. I downvote sloppy questions quite frequently. I reserve my downvotes on answers to material that's harmful: that will introduce bugs into software if people use it. And I try to explain my answer downvotes.

Comment: I constantly seem to run into questions showing no research effort, have no future value and don't have enough information that get nothing but upvotes - that's probably a better signal that things are not okay than a purely numerical stat.

Comment: Very good questions can get thousands of upvotes. Very bad questions get a few downvotes and are deleted/closed/hidden. Many more people will see and get the chance to vote on good questions than bad ones.

Comment: @Servy Based on my experience, it seems closer to about -0.95x more good content than bad.

Comment: @Dukeling Is that with or without showing deleted content?

Comment: A lot of people remember that there's a penalty to downvote an answer and forget there's no penalty to downvote a question.

Comment: What would it mean for this ratio to "make sense" or not? It's the ratio. By definition it makes sense. What am I missing?

Comment: @KevinWorkman I take "makes sense" in this context to mean "is an accurate representation of the quality distribution of posts".

Comment: Downvoted post can be improved and consequently some downvotes get retracted and upvotes start to come in. Upvoted posts usually do not get worsened and keep attracting upvotes.

Comment: @TaW While that's possible, it's quite rare for bad posts to *actually* be improved (to a significant degree).  By far the more relevant factor is that the really bad posts simply get *deleted*, and don't contribute to the stat.

Comment: True although I see both happening every day. So we have a number of factors skweing the stats towards the upvotes. The point I made was esp. about long-term changes, which almost all go for upvotes..

Comment: I was about to say this question has more downvotes than average, but I suspect as the saying goes, meta is different...

Comment: @Draco18s Well, I'm not talking about users who down vote sparingly. I'm talking about users who view down votes as mean or even immoral and thus don't do it *at all*. You don't fall into that category.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Consider this graph of score distribution:

[image: Score distribution]

As you can see, the most common score for a post is 0. While some of those posts are something like +1/-1, far and away the majority of these posts are simply ignored by the community. If they *do* get a vote, +1 and +2 are more common than -1. Stretching that disparity across the long tails of each extreme gets us to the 6:1 ratio.

According to [Sturgeon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon%27s_law) and evaluating random samples of posts, we might expect something closer to one great post for every 6 not-so-great post. But votes on Stack Overflow tend to strongly correlate with views which (hopefully) correlate to quality in turn. Truly unhelpful posts tend to be seen by a handful of people and then ignored forever. Truly useful posts will accumulate upvotes for just as long. Truly terrible posts tend to get deleted.

Looking *just* at deleted posts we see a different profile:

[image: Score distribution on deleted posts]

My guess is that many of the positively scored posts in this sample are answers to deleted questions. (Feel free to verify that guess using SEDE. [My queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/676387/up-vs-downvotes?limit=10#graph) ought to be a good starting place.) Of course, once a post is deleted, it can't get more votes of any sort. That means there's a structural reason for more upvotes than downvotes.

Finally, there's an active disincentive for downvoting answers. When we removed the -1 penalty for downvoting questions, there was an [immediate increase in question downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242839/1438). (There's also a small impact from increasing the quota of question downvotes at the same time.)

### Summary

It's difficult to know what the "right level" of downvoting might be, but many posts are ignored or deleted rather than downvoted. As a result, useful posts tend to accumulate votes while unhelpful posts don't.

Comment: If someone shows a code editor in a talk, someone will inevitably say "embiggen". If someone shows a graph, will someone inevitably say "make the y axis log scale"? (Though the point is well and truly shown with a linear scale)

Comment: [Deleted with log 10](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/676387/up-vs-downvotes?limit=10#graph), [Undeleted with log 10](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/676662/up-vs-downvotes?limit=10#graph)

Comment: A bar chart would be better, wouldn't? There are no values for the fractions, but only integer values.

Comment: @usr1234567: Yep. But SEDE puts out line charts by default, so I used that. ;-)